# How to set arguments on Symfony Assets

Tags: symfony, assets

I use the jsqueeze assets filter for my project and digged in the code.
For me, it seems like the squeeze() function is beign called on the js files given.
Now i want to set the renaming variables argument on the squeeze function, but it is a third-party-bundle and i haven't found a solution to configure it in the config.yml where the filter is defined.

Answer (score 2):

I found out where the magic happens.

All possible configurations are stored in the symfony assetics-bundle:
vendor>symfony>assetics-bundle>Resources>config>filters

For each filter, there is an xml file with the parameters you are able to change.
It took me a lot of time to find this, i think it is not documented in the symfony documentation.